# Rails don't show API object if it matches database object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4

My app pulls in group objects using an API from Meetup.com. These objects don't go into my database. Users can then add a group to their profile, at which point it does enter my database.

When the user logs back into my site, I don't want to show them the group objects from Meetup.com that they've already added to their profile.The shared key here is meetup.com objects have a "group.id" that matches my database "group" model's "group_id"

If the groups from the API were database objects, I imagine I could do something like this:

```
@groups = RMeetup::Client.fetch(:groups, :lat => @user.latitude, :lon => @user.longitude)
@justnewgroups = @groups.where("id NOT IN (?)", current_user.groups.pluck(:group_id)
```

But I don't know how to do it without using where. Maybe something like this in the view?:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
   <% unless group.id == current_user.groups.pluck(:group_id) %>
     <%= render :partial => 'groups/group', :locals => { :group => group } %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but none of the user's groups are being excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_groups = RMeetup::Client.fetch(:groups, :lat => @user.latitude, :lon => @user.longitude)
current_group_ids = current_user.groups.pluck(:group_id)
@groups = new_groups.reject { |group| current_group_ids.include?(group.id) }
```